# How can i use Time text in Java on wear os. Google docs only support Kotlin for now

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I want to display the time at the top of my wear-os application. This is for one because it should be a common practise and for other, because Google will enforce it on the Playstore soon according to IO.

Since Google is kind off switching everything to Kotlin first, they have not made documentation to implement their Time text layout in Java. Which should be used in all applications as a standard, and adapts to round and square screens. Link: https://developer.android.com/design/ui/wear/guides/components/time-text

Now of course, i could be using a setText() together with a runnable. But that wouldnt be up to standards and would not adapt to screen type.

How do i implement Time text in Java?

I expected to find Time text in the XML recommendations. However it wasn't to be found.

Comment: `TimeText()` is part of Wear Compose, a series of composables for Jetpack Compose that target Wear OS. Wear Compose, like Jetpack Compose, is only usable from Kotlin. You may be able to minimize how much Kotlin you need to use, wrapping your `Scaffold()` and `TimeText()` in a `ComposeView` that you use in a layout, but this may be tricky. Otherwise, you will be on your own for implementing a `TimeText()` equivalent in Java. Or, you could learn Kotlin and use Wear Compose directly.

Comment: i will be using Kotlin for my new wear app, but i just want to update my existing app. anyhow your right i might need to implement it myself then

Answer (score 2):

Use this sample code for Views https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/main/TimeText/timetext/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/timetext/TimeText.kt

https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/main/TimeText/wear/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.wearable.timetext.TimeText
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:titleTextColor="#82b1ff"
        app:titleText="ABC" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add ComposeView to your layout.xml just as you would any other View:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Create a new kt file, for example ComposeFunctions.kt that has a function to set the content to the ComposeView:

```
@file:JvmName("ComposeFunctions")

package (your package goes here)

import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.wear.compose.material.TimeText

fun setContent(composeView: ComposeView) {
    composeView.setContent { TimeText() }
}
```

Now from your java Activity/Fragment

```
ComposeView composeView = view.findViewById(R.id.compose_view);
ComposeFunctions.setContent(composeView);
```

Please note that for the above to work you'll need to add the required kotlin and compose dependencies to build.gradle (project and wearOS app).